# Ionic $scope.function only firing once, then giving error on new clicks

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Last week I made a function that takes a true/false value out of a pair of buttons (one for true, one for false) and puts it into a $scope variable.

It worked perfectly.

```js
  $scope.trueOrFalse = function(truefalse) {
    if (truefalse == false){
      $scope.value = false;
      document.getElementById("makeFalse").className = "button active";
      document.getElementById("makeTrue").className = "button";
      console.log($scope.isBusiness);
    } else if(truefalse == true){
      $scope.value = true;
      document.getElementById("makeTrue").className = "button active";
      document.getElementById("makeFalse").className = "button";
      console.log($scope.value);
    }
  }
```

But now, I have basically the same exact thing in another page, and its only working once, on the first click, where, if the chosen value is false, I get a console.log that it is false, then nothing happen if clicked again, to change the value.

But if the value chosen is true, then when the next click is attempted, I start to get:

TypeError: fn is not a function

```
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21045); 
at ionic.bundle.js:53458; 
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100); 
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199); 
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457); 
at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713); 
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863); 
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852); 
at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:2925);
```

What's going on here?

Here's the HTML

```html
<ion-view view-title="Biz Post/Uploading">
  <ion-content>
         

  <!-- Begin Second Set of Tabs -->
  <div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button" id="item" data-ng-click="isDeal(false)">Item</a>
    <a class="button" id="deal" data-ng-click="isDeal(true)">Deal</a>
  </div>
  <!-- End Second Set of Tabs -->

  <!-- Section -->
  <div class="list-inset">
    <center><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></center>
  </div>


    <div class="list">
     <div class="item item-divider">
         Add thing
       </div>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">thing</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="add location" ng-model="thing.thing2">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">thing</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="add price" ng-model="thing.thing3">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">thing</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="add item description" ng-model="item.thing">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Date</span>
  <input type="date">
</label>
     <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">thing</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="set limit" ng-model="thing.thing4">
      </label>

          <button class="button button-full button-balanced" data-ng-click="pushData()">
           push data
          </button>

    
       </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Please show also the code html with the two buttons

Comment: Is the controller being loaded on the new page? Perhaps scope isn't being updated until after the first click.

Comment: Yeah, the controller is loaded, and it prints out the first console.log of true or false value

Comment: there we go :) thanks!

Comment: Have  a look at ng-class. It's works better to have $scope.truefalse = true ;and in the html: <button id="makeTrue" ng-class="{button :true, active: truefalse}">Make true</button>

Comment: doing thing in JQUERY for an angularApp is not the way to do. You are messing up the angular Digest loop. Have a loop at ng-class that let you put condition for classes

Comment: there is no Jquery here

Comment: @AnaF I don't understand what you mean with that.

Answer (score 0):

With ng-class the code would look like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6sOzUmAcIzVjLEOL9Jva?p=preview

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <button id="makeTrue" ng-class="{button :true, active: truefalse}" ng-click="truefalse = !truefalse">Make true</button>
      <button id="makeFalse" ng-class="{button :true, active: !truefalse} " ng-click="truefalse = !truefalse">Make false</button>
    </div>
```

In controller: `$scope.truefalse = true;`. If truefalse is true, then makeTrue has the active class (that seems a bit off, but it's the same in your code), otherwise makeFalse is active.

This way you're not playing with the DOM in your controller(which should be avoided).And your $scope is less cluttered.

For the ng-click you can define a function on $scope and call it instead of changing truefalse in an expression (but that's up to you)